# Exception Value: Cannot use None as a query value Django Framework

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, valueerror

Help required, please.
I'm doing a level 6 Diploma in Software Development. Right now I'm doing a project that requires a gym app to be built.
We've decided on using Python/Django as our language/framework.

I have my models, urls, views, and templates working thus far. (Videos display and its own page)
However, I need to implement a search bar to search both video content and text context within the app.
I have the video model set up in /admin. migrations are done.
Do I need another model to search for normal content in my app?
The search bar is in my base.html template.

I want to use the search bar to do a query and pass the results onto a results template page
which extends base.html.
The error I get is the below;

Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: Cannot use None as a query value

Can someone point me in the right direction? photos of code attached.

base.html

```
<!-- Navbar Right Side -->
<div class="navbar-nav">
    <form class="form-inline my-1 my-lg-0" action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="get">
        <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <a class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" href='/gymapp/videos/' type=submit>Search</a>
    </form>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Login</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="/register">Register</a>
</div>
```

search_results.html

```
{% extends "gymapp/base.html" %}
{% load embed_video_tags %}
{% block content %}
    {% for i in obj %}
        {% video i.video 'tiny' %}
            <ul class="list-unstyled mt-3 mb-4">
                <li>Name: {{ i.video_name }}</li>
               <li>Description: {{ i.content }}</li>
            </ul>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

urls.py

```
path('videos/', VideoResultsView.as_view(), name='search_results'),
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from embed_video.fields import EmbedVideoField


class Video(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    video_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    content = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    video = EmbedVideoField()  # same like models.URLField()
    stats = models.CharField(max_length=20)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'videos'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.category
```

views.py

```
class VideoResultsView(ListView):
    model = Video
    template_name = 'search_results.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        video_list = Video.objects.filter(
            Q(category__icontains=query) | Q(video_name__icontains=query)
        )
        return video_list
```

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction. [Error Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aiii.png)

Comment: Check if the variable `query` is not empty. If it is, dont use `filter()` but use `all()` instead, since (eg. `if not query: video_list = Video.objects.all() else: # current code you have`

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer.

```
<form class="form-inline my-1 my-lg-0" action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="get">
    <input name="q" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
    <a class="btn btn-secondary my-2 my-sm-0" href='/gymapp/videos/' type=submit>Search</a>
</form>
```

I shouldn't have used an  tag for the button. Changed it to  tag and now the query is working.

silly mistake.

Comment: So you changed it to button, I reckon. Tip: Change type of the input to "search", then it semantically correct and you get some [bonus behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/search#Using_search_inputs). Also, you can get rid of the button - the form will be submitted upon pressing enter and it's quite natural for people to do so.